# How to make a general CSS for Tablet devices in Landscape & portrait view?

Tags: android, ipad, windows-mobile, tablet

How can I make global styles for Tablet devices in Landscape & portrait view?
I have a website I want to make it compatible for All mobile devices.
Main goal is that It should be compatible in Portrait & Landscape view I want make common CSS in as below devices

1. Samsung Tablet (Android),
2. iPad( version 1.0/2.0 latest), and
3. Windows8 Tablet..

So I am confusing to make a global or general CSS style to make it simillar to all most three above tablates.

Comment: what about using device size and orientation detection: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/04/targeted-css/ and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170931/detecting-screen-resolution-to-load-alternative-css-a-good-idea

Comment: @josef Hi, It fixed sized in Samsung , Ipad2 & windows Tabs. Thanks a lot to give me good reference url for make a good styles.

Comment: Use bootstrap framework

Comment: @SnakeEyes yes. now it will work. but at that time development bootstrap was newer and not light up in market..
thank you  SnakeEyes