# Is there a high dpi switch for Internet Explorer (like Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, dpi, shortcut-file

For google chrome, you can enable high DPI support by enabling following switch in google chrome shortcut.

```
/high-dpi-support=1
```

[image]

Is there a way to enable such switch for **Internet Explorer**? I am using Internet Explorer 11.0 on window 7.

Answer (score 0):

no there is no command line switch for IE for that feature. IE11 also does not support the picture element. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Pity! What is the picture element support?

Comment: Hi, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689715/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-retina-support-on-a-device-using-javascript... you than can use an picture element and an image array to only request those image resources that the client screen supports. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170931/detecting-screen-resolution-to-load-alternative-css-a-good-idea